# class="js-dropdown" and class="js-dropdown-menu" broke after angular upgrade

Tags: html, css, angular

We upgraded from Angular 4 to Angular 8.1 and a lot of our drop downs are broken.  From what I can tell they all contain these two style classes: the class js-dropdown and js-dropdown-menu.  We can't find where these style classes are coming from or how they work.  It's hard to search these terms on google because there's no way to have a must-include for hyphens, that I know of.  Here's an example of the html:

```
     <div class="select-wrapper" id="searchOption">
        <li class="dropdown nav__item is-parent" tabindex="0" style="outline: 0" (blur)="closeDropdown($event)">
            <div class="select-dropdown js-dropdown">
                <span class="selection">{{ searchType }}</span>
                <i class="nav__icon nav__icon--dropdown"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="details-search nav__menu js-dropdown-menu">
                <li (click)="optionSelected($event, 1)">
                    <a class="nav__link">Option 1</a>
                </li>
                <li (click)="optionSelected($event, 2)">
                    <a class="nav__link">Option 2</a>
                </li>
                <li (click)="optionSelected($event, 3)">
                    <a class="nav__link">Option 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
```

Does anyone have any insight to the class js-dropdown and js-dropdown-menu and how to fix them after this upgrade?

Update: so i think i found out where the js-dropdown style class comes from.... it doesn't come from any style... it's just used as a label and component.js looks for that label to show or hide it.  The now is that component.js function isn't getting called.  Anyone know how to fix this?

```
$('#app-container').on('click', '.js-dropdown, .js-dropdown-menu > *', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

var that = this;
var parent = $(this).closest('.is-parent');

//is our dropdown open?
if(!parent.hasClass('is-open')){
  //... then open it.
  parent.addClass('is-open');

  //handle clicking away
  $(document).one('click', function closeMenu(docEvent){
    //if the parent does not contain the clicked element...
    if($(parent).has(docEvent.target).length === 0) {
        //close it.
        parent.removeClass('is-open');
    } else {
      // else, set up another listener to check the next user click.
      $(document).one('click', closeMenu);
    }
  });

} else {
  // ...else we close it.
  parent.removeClass('is-open');
}
event.stopPropagation();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  We were not loading a components.js file (as well as other scripts) in the angular.json file. Our previous version of angular did not contain an angular.json file.